# Adding widget to WordPress frontpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I created a website in WordPress (Website: [Link](https://www.terapieapavie.ro/)) using this [theme](https://demo.themefreesia.com/idyllic/).

I would like to know, how can I add a [timeline-express] widget after the image slider?

(I tried to modify idyllic-functions.php, using:

```
...
</div> <!-- end .main-slider -->';
echo $idyllic_category_sliders_display;
echo add_filter( 'widget_text', 'timeline-express');
...
```

,but the site crashes.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file: **idyllic/inc/front-page/front-page-features.php** and add this following line on line 34:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[timeline-express]'); ?>
```

Just above this line:

```
<div class="our-feature-box <?php echo esc_attr($feature_box_class); ?>">
```

So, your updated code will be also follows:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[timeline-express]'); ?>
<div class="our-feature-box <?php echo esc_attr($feature_box_class); ?>">
```

Note that, it's always a good practice to create a child theme, copy file/template to the child theme directory, and then modify your codes. Otherwise, you will lose your modified codes once the theme is updated.

**PS:** please try to follow what @tacoshy mentioned in his comment while asking questions in stackoverflow.